# Computing derivative with vectors and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I do not have much knowledge on derivatives for vectors and matrices. Could someone please help me computing the derivative of following equation and showing me all the steps, please?

$f(\theta) = \langle a, A \theta \rangle + \lambda ( \langle (\theta^+ - \theta), A(\theta^+ - \theta) \rangle - \alpha )$

where $a, \theta, \theta^*$ are vectors of size $d$, A a matrix of size $d \times d$,  and $\lambda, \alpha$ are scalars.

Comment: First step would be to write the inner product in matrix product terms. Then have a look at the matrix cookbook: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference! So it would be $ b^{\top} B - 2 \lambda B (\theta^* - \theta) = 0$, could you please tell me if it's correct? Then, I get $\theta^{*} = \theta - \frac{b^{\top} I_d}{2 \lambda}$ but I don't know if it's correct and I don't really know how to proceed. I then need to find $\theta$ using this other equation: $\lambda \langle (\theta^* - \theta), B(\theta^* - \theta) \rangle - \beta = 0$. But I'm not use to work with vectors and matrices so I don't know what the steps should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of hints. The derivative is still linear, so l writing:

> $f = f_1 + f_2$

For the two expressions. We have

$df = df_1 + df_2$

So we can work out the derivative of each function seperately. Second, we have:

> $ d<f,g> = <df, g> + <f, dg>$

And also for $A$ a constant matrix and so representing a linear map:

> $dA = A$

Then:

> $d<a, A\theta>$

> $= <da, A\theta> + <a, d(A\theta)>$

> $ = 0 + <a, A\theta>$

> $= <a,A\theta>$

Comment: Thank you very very much! Just a question for the last step: when you write $\langle a, d(A\theta) \rangle$ shouldn't it be equal to $ \langle a, A \rangle$ instead of $\langle a, A \theta \rangle$ ?